# SSH Permission denied for Mininet

Tags: linux, ssh, mininet, sdn

I am new to SDN and was trying to learn Mininet. I have installed debian(64-bit) and Mininet on Virtual Box. When I try to connect Mininet Vm from Debian I have to run the following comamnd :

```
ssh -X mininet@10.0.2.15
```

It asks for mininet password, but after entering the default mininet password it shows an error

```
Permission denied please try again
```

Both my debian and Mininet VM have same IP address. Kindly guide how to eliminate the SSHerror. Also is it fine having same ip address for two different VM, is the SSH error a result of this ?
Thanks

Comment: can you start the virtual machine and use its terminal to check if it has acquired an IP?

Answer (score 4):

In the **VirtualBox** settings under the tab **Network** click on **Advanced** then **Port Forwarding** and add a rule with name: ssh, protocol: tcp, host port: 3022 and guest port: 22. Then execute:

```
sudo ssh -p 3022 mininet@10.0.2.15
```